Обнаружение заморозки процесса
Возможно ли как-то обнаружить, были ли потоки моего процесса заморожены с использованием утилиты вроде "ProcessHacker"? Я пытался реализовать эту задачу, но безуспешно.
Владею следующей информацией. Пример проверки на C: https://github.com/winsiderss/systeminformer/blob/82236c5c04c3a7d7c193aa9e0e6092a5de9b7ce7/ProcessHacker/appsup.c#L54-L91.
Я знаю, что можно перечислить все потоки и проверить, приостановлены ли они, но не уверен, как сделать это надежно, чтобы не допустить обхода с стороны юзера. Я предпринимаю эти действия, чтобы предотвратить внедрение в мой процесс и любые нежелательные манипуляции в нем.
Конечно основная задача стоит в том, чтобы атакующему пользователю, который хочет заморозить процесс, было крайне тяжело заморозить проверяющий процесс или чтобы не использовалось для детекта заморозки.

Для какой ОС используете термин "заморозить"?
